# Executing a function with parameter with execute() vaadin

Tags: javascript, java, callback, vaadin, vaadin7

if I want to execute a function on the js side, which is called from the java side using the execute() method, and pass a parameter to it, how would I go about it? Basically say I have a js function called callbackFnct defined in the js as:

```
callbackFnct:function(param1){
    console.log("callbackFnct() called");
}
```

which is called from the java side with

```
public void javafunction(String myParam, String callbackFnc){
  com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(callbackFnc);
```

also the javafunction is a RPC call defined in the relevant interface as

```
public void javafunction (String myParam, String callbackFnc);
```

How do I pass a parameter to the callbackFnc? If I do something like

```
com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(callbackFnc(theParam));
```

the compiler complains, quite rightly, saying that 
`The method callbackFnc(theParam) is undefined for the type new IFileUploaderServerRpc(){}` 
because of course in the RPC interface callbackFnc is a string

Comment: What would the JS function do when called? What is it you're trying to achieve? I'm asking because you should be able to do what you're asking with an [`AbstractJavaScriptExtension`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/AbstractJavaScriptExtension.html) but perhaps there's a simpler way...

Comment: well, a bit of a long story but the callback function was simply displaying something in the console with the view of then doing sth else. Anyway, looks like this is the way to go: 
`com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(callbackFnc + "(" + parameter + ")");`